# MySQL sorting and subtraction/addition values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which contains users and money they spent in total. If Bob spent 100, and after that we have Bob=>170, means he spent extra 70;
I wrote command which make my table like right one. Here is my code:

```
SELECT `name`, `Money`, `date` FROM `Money` WHERE `date` > "2000-12-30" AND `date` < "2003-12-31"ORDER BY `name`, `Money` ASC;
```

Unsorted________________________Sorted by name and money spent

```
|id|name  |Money|date      |    |id|name  |Money|date      |
|__|______|_____|__________|    |__|______|_____|__________|
|1 |Bob   |100  |01/01/2000|    |1 |Bob   |100  |01/01/2000|
|2 |Josh  |150  |02/02/2000|    |2 |Bob   |170  |01/01/2001|
|3 |Bob   |170  |01/01/2001|    |3 |Bob   |210  |02/02/2002| 
|4 |Den   |130  |02/02/2000|    |4 |Bob   |240  |02/02/2003|
|5 |Cherry|140  |02/02/2000|    |5 |Cherry|140  |02/02/2000|
|6 |Den   |180  |02/02/2001|    |6 |Cherry|240  |02/02/2001|
|7 |Ron   |150  |02/02/2000|    |7 |Den   |130  |02/02/2000|
|8 |Bob   |210  |02/02/2003|    |8 |Den   |180  |02/02/2001|
|9 |Ron   |210  |02/02/2001|    |9 |Josh  |150  |02/02/2000|
|10|Bob   |240  |02/02/2004|    |10|Josh  |270  |02/02/2001|
|11|Cherry|240  |02/02/2001|    |11|Ron   |150  |02/02/2000|
|12|Josh  |270  |02/02/2001|    |12|Ron   |210  |02/02/2001|
```

Now, I need to sum all money which was spent between 2001(included) and 2003. Excluding sum which was spent before 2000. Looks like it should be 470.

I can't find command how to sum up. Also I can't create new tables and should do this using just one command without php, pure MySQL. I spouse I need to use sub query, I have tried, but I am not confident with then, I am new in MySQL.

Comment: Can you write the dates the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Your columns name in select don't match with columns name in sample  so i use column name in sample

if you want a sum for a name  between a period you can use  group by  eg:

```
select name, sum(money)
from my_table 
WHERE `date` between str_to_date('1999-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')  AND ('2009-12-31', '%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name ASC
```

assuming also that your date column is date data type

Answer (score 0):

The query (plate, milage, date between 1999 and 2009) doesn't seem to have to do anything with the table and problem you describe. Have you posted a wrong query?

Anyway, you can look at the maximum money per name before 2001 and after and subtract the former from the latter:

```
select sum(money_spent)
from
(
  select
    max(case when year(date) >= 2001 then money end) -
    coalesce(max(case when year(date) < 2001 then money end), 0) as money_spent
  from mytable
  where year(date) <= 2003
  group by name
) money_spent_per_name;
```

Comment: yes, I just update my query. Thank you for your respond